# excel linking cells and retain hyperlink in the master cells

Tags: ios, excel

I have a simple question (I think) of how to link two cells in Excel. I have a tab with a list of `master cells` that all contain **hyperlinks** to websites. I regularly need to update these links.

In other tabs I need to make new combinations of this list. I would like to be able to link to the 'master cells' in the first row and retain the hyperlink, so that the hyperlinks to websites are retained in the tabs with the new combinations. Is this possible? When I link regularly by typing `=` and clicking the cell in the 'master cell-tab I only get the text and not the **hyperlink** to the website.
Thanks :)

Comment: Try to provide some relevant code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Hyperlink function. If you use a cell reference as the first input, it'll use the hyperlink attached to that cell.

For example, let's say Cell A1 contains the link "[excel linking cells and retain hyperlink in the master cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196032/excel-linking-cells-and-retain-hyperlink-in-the-master-cells)". If you input the formula `=HYPERLINK(A1, "Click here")` into Cell A2, you'll be able to click on A2 and it'll use the hyperlink attached to A1

Note that this doesn't work when chaining references (e.g. if we continue with the previous example, and you put the hyperlink formula in A3 referring to A2, it'll fail and prompt you that there is an error with the link).